# docker-compose redis and redis commander

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I use the windows docker toolbox and I am confused what I am missing. I want to use redis commander (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-commander) with a docker image redis from the docker hub.

I used the docker-compose.yml from above link:

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    image: redis

  redis-commander:
    container_name: redis-commander
    hostname: redis-commander
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    build: .
    restart: always
    environment:
    - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
    ports:
    - 8081:8081
```

Now I can start the app with the toolbox IP on port 8081
Ther it says undefined redis server: local:redis:6379:0

Since I am using the toolbox I assume I have to put some IP correct in the compose file.

Using redis alone with `$ docker run --name some-redis -d redis`

works and I can reach the server und er local:6379

But what means `REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379`

Any help to set this up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

i think you missed to link your 2 containers.
the redis container needs a port + link and the redis-commander the correct environment.
you can only use the container name for the link/environment.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    image: redis
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"
    links: redis-commander

  redis-commander:
    container_name: redis-commander
    hostname: redis-commander
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    build: .
    restart: always
    environment:
        - REDIS_HOSTS=redis
    ports:
        - "8081:8081"
```

Comment: Thanky. I found something here. Where is the difference, I mean this is much less code and redis commander has no environment there: https://github.com/tenstartups/redis-commander-docker

Answer (score 1):

For fix that you need link redis and redis-commander like that:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.5
    command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - redis:/var/lib/redis
      - redis-config:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - ${REDIS_PORT}:6379
    networks:
      - redis-network

  redis-commander:
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      REDIS_HOSTS: redis
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: redis:6379
      REDIS_PASSWORD: ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
      HTTP_USER: root
      HTTP_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - redis-network

volumes:
  redis:
  redis-config:

networks:
  redis-network:
    driver: bridge
```

or that:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.5
    command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - redis:/var/lib/redis
      - redis-config:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - ${REDIS_PORT}:6379
    links:
      - redis-commander

  redis-commander:
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      REDIS_HOSTS: redis
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      REDIS_PORT: redis:6379
      REDIS_PASSWORD: ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
      HTTP_USER: root
      HTTP_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 8081:8081

volumes:
  redis:
  redis-config:
```

Answer (score 0):

`REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379` means it will create config file to connect to docker container with the *hostname* `redis` on *port* `6379` and will have the connection *name* or *label* as `local`.

`REDIS_HOSTS` is used when you want to have multiple connection, separated by comma.
There are some ways to write `REDIS_HOSTS` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/rediscommander/redis-commander).

`hostname`

`label:hostname`

`label:hostname:port`

`label:hostname:port:dbIndex`

`label:hostname:port:dbIndex:password`

Example:
Let say you want to use redis for two app called `app1` and `app2`. `app1` will have the db index 1, `app2` will have the db index 2. The `REDIS_HOSTS` would look like:

`REDIS_HOSTS=app1:redis:6379:1,app2:redis:6379:2`

The working docker-compose.yml you could use (add network):

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    image: redis
    networks:
      - redis_network

  redis-commander:
    container_name: redis-commander
    hostname: redis-commander
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    build: .
    restart: always
    environment:
    - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
    ports:
    - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - redis_network
networks:
  redis_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code and it works

```
redis:
  container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-redis
  image: redis:alpine
  hostname: ${REDIS_HOST}
  command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD} --bind 0.0.0.0
  environment:
    - REDIS_PASSWORD=${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    - REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT}
  ports:
    - ${REDIS_PORT}:${REDIS_PORT}
  volumes:
    - redis:/data
  networks:
    - sample_network
  restart: unless-stopped

redis-commander:
  container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-redis-commander
  image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
  hostname: ${REDIS_COMMANDER_HOST}
  depends_on:
    - redis
  environment:
    - REDIS_HOST=${REDIS_HOST}
    - REDIS_PORT=${REDIS_PORT}
    - REDIS_PASSWORD=${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    - HTTP_USER=${REDIS_COMMANDER_USER}
    - HTTP_PASSWORD=${REDIS_COMMANDER_PASS}
  ports:
    - "8081:8081"
  networks:
    - sample_network
  restart: unless-stopped
```

Don't forget Valium

```
volumes:
  redis:
    driver: local
    name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_redis
```